# How should we use [fingerprint]s?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a suggested edit to the [fingerprint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerprint) wiki defining it as the biometric fingerprint. But the actual use is rather mixed: there are several questions talking about key fingerprints (~1/3rd of the questions).

Should we tag the key fingerprint questions with something else?

Comment: Given the low rate of questions (25 as of today) and the "rather mixed" use, I'd highly encourage anyone listening to include good cross-reference guidance in the tag excerpts. If we end up splitting every "fingerprint" usage to separate tags, it might be worth a disambiguation tag excerpt on "fingerprint" to point the way to the correct tags.

Comment: @JeffSchaller is +6/-0 on the top answer enough for a consensus?

Comment: Seems pretty undisputed to me. Do you need moderator intervention for any of this? I'm happy to help, it's just that I don't think I'm needed (retagging questions and updating tag wiki/excerpts is a 5k privilege, I think).

Answer (score 8):

I think that we should split it up into two clearer tags:

- [fingerprint-authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerprint-authentication), for biometric fingerprinting, and
- [key-fingerprint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-fingerprint), for key fingerprints

We would then retag all questions with [fingerprint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerprint) to use one of these two tags.

We might also create a synonym from [fingerprint-reader](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerprint-reader) to [fingerprint-authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerprint-authentication).

A suggested tag wiki for [fingerprint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerprint) after the change:

> For questions about biometric fingerprinting or fingerprint readers, please tag with [fingerprint-authentication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerprint-authentication). For questions about key fingerprints in relation to cryptography, please tag with [key-fingerprint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-fingerprint).

Comment: I like this, but maybe fingerprint-authentication instead of biometric-fingerprint

Comment: @muru That's the word I was looking for! Incorporated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since we live in the real world, even on a technical site real-world scenarios feel more common-sense (and less likely to be mistagged in the future).

So, if I were looking for an appropriate tag, I'd feel that "fingerprint" (being a common term amongst non-technical people) is more intuitive than "biometric". For example, many laptops and phones now come with a "fingerprint reader", and far less often marketed as a "biometric device" (although I have seen it once or twice when selling security systems in particular).

I'd therefore argue that dividing it into:

- [fingerprint-biometric](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerprint-biometric) for biometric devices designed to read fingers; and
- [fingerprint-cryptographic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fingerprint-cryptographic) for cryptographic routines that

would be more likely to guide taggers to the right tag.

In general, I'd say "concept-industry" would be a good tag scheme in this case, however I also see that there's an overlap.  For example, understanding the cryptography in fingerprint readers (to prevent MITM attacks) would fall under either (or both) tags.  So there isn't a perfect answer here.